# In Fortran, what is the best way to choose a non-zero element at random from an array?

Tags: arrays, indexing, fortran

I have a 1D array of integers with a non-zero value at some indices, the remaining being zero. The non-zero value is equal to the index. E.g.:

```
CHOOSEARRAY = (/0,0,0,4,0,6,7/)
```

I want to choose at random any non-zero element from this array. In this case, I want the output to be either 4,6 or 7 with equal probability.

My current approach is slightly convoluted and works as follows:

Count the number of available choices

```
NCHOICE = COUNT(CHOOSEARRAY.NE.0)
```

Create an array, and fill it with the non-zero values

```
ALLOCATE(CHOICES(NCHOICE))
CHOICES = PACK(CHOOSEARRAY,CHOOSEARRAY.NE.0)
```

Choose a random element from this new array

```
CHOSENVAL = CHOICES(FLOOR(1+GRND()*NCHOICE))
```

Here, GRND() is a random number generating function that outputs a real number uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

This code block has to be repeated multiple times, requiring multiple allocation and deallocation operations which can be time consuming. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Alternatively, is there a way to return the index of a randomly chosen non-zero element? For e.g. (/0,1,1,0,0,1/) should give either 2,3, or 6 with equal probability.

Comment: You can do this without the `choices` allocation, but have you profiled this to determine whether the allocation costs are significant in your cases or interest?

Comment: Do you know a priori how many non-zero elements there are?

Comment: @IanBush, it's not known apriori, hence the allocation and deallocation.

Comment: @francescalus I haven't profiled this, but the operation occurs over 10,000 times. I am going off the assumption that allocating and deallocating this often is not generally a good idea for speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not scared of a few divisions by zero this might appeal.  First, let's have some random numbers ...

```
REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(choosearray)) :: rands
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rands)
```

then we can get the location of a random non-zero element from `choosearray` with the expression

```
MAXLOC(rands * choosearray/choosearray)
```

and then get its value with

```
choosearray(MAXLOC(rands * choosearray/choosearray))
```

I'll leave it to you to test the speed of this.

Comment: Very interesting approach! I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay, this approach seems to work the best. I modified my choosearray so that it has either ones or zeros. Multiplying by a random array of the same size and choosing the position of the largest element works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are optimising for: speed, space or readability of your code?

If space, you could count the number of zeroes and subtract it from the length of the array (only takes up a single integer), then generate a random index n between 1 and n and then find the n-th non-zero number in the array. This is roughly O(2n).

If speed, you should probably loop over the array, copying non-zeroes as you go and then select at random from the resulting array (which needs to be the same size as the original to accommodate all values) - this is O(n), but costs the same amount of memory as the original array.

Whether it's actually faster depends on the speed of the implementation of the copy operation vs. just a read operation. The 'big oh' only tells you the order of the algorithm, you'll have to test to know whether the operations you use actually confer the benefit you expect.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I am primarily optimizing for speed here. I am not sure how the second suggestion would be implemented. Say I get an array (/1,4,7,0,0,0,0/) by copying nonzeros as I go, but how would I select one at random?